# How to combine a layout and a view?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am making an 2D Android game with Android Studio and I have a `activity_customer.xml` file and I have a `MyView a`
but when I use like this, `MyView a` isn't seen on the screen but `activity_customer.xml` is seen on the screen  :

```
Customer.java:

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MyView a = new MyView(this);
        setContentView(a);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_customer);
}
```

But if I use like this,`MyView a` is seen on the screen but `activity_customer.xml` isn't seen on the screen  :

```
 Customer.java:

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MyView a = new MyView(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_customer);
        setContentView(a);

}
```

So I want to seen both `MyView a` and `activity_customer.xml` ,How can I combine them in a one screen?

This is my `activity_customer.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.asdf.catchtheball.main">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:text="Button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you created your own view class you can add it to your activity view with something like this:

```
RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout); //Your main element at activity's xml file
mainLayout.addView(yourView); // replace your 'a' object with 'yourView'
```

Comment: What is `R.id.mainlayout` I haven't like this id ? and also How should I call `setContentView` method?

Comment: @DijitalDünya i replaced it with your xml id :)

Comment: @Reza.Abedini Thanks, could you show which parameter can I call the setContentView?

Comment: @Reza.Abedini And also this line doesn't work :
`RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_customer.xml);`

Comment: i fixed that, you should set an id for your main relativeLayout and then use that id for findViewById method.

Comment: You should write setContentView(R.layout.activity_customer); and then use my code

Comment: @Reza.Abedini thanks a lot, and lastly could you show how can I add MyView class to my activity view?

Comment: use mainLayout.addView(myView) to  add your view to activity